# how to open non-secure http Webpage in Webview android

Tags: android, http, webview

I want to open Webpage in Webview. I know all https links can open in Webview. But I need to open http(not https) version of web page in Webview. I have no idea how to do it.

For https web page I had tried this.

```
private WebView webView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    //open http in webview
    webView.loadUrl("http://skystreamhubs.com/");
    //webView.loadUrl("http://skystreamhub.com/");

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            view.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString());
            return false;
        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                if (webView.canGoBack()) {
                    webView.goBack();
                } else {
                    finish();
                }
                return true;
        }

    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: SLaks Thanks for quick response. You mean its not possible at all ?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: No error just white blank screen. I want to open this link. http://skystreamhub.com/